# How does maven compile only the modified java files?

Tags: java, maven, compilation, maven-3, last-modified

I was just curious to know this, when i give mvn install without doing 'clean', maven compiles only the modified java files. How does maven identify a java file is modified or not? I believe it is not using the last modified property of the file.

Reason for my belief: I had a module, after merging a change from svn, i gave mvn install and it didn't compile the modified file and when i looked at the change i saw that 'long' were modified to 'Long' in getters and setters.

So i just want to know how maven identifies if a java file has changed or not?

(P.S I'm using Apache Maven 3.0.3, if that matters)

Comment: what if the module is not under version control?

Comment: then (time of class file < time of source file) => modified

Comment: @Fakrudeen In that case Maven should change timestamp of the source file, but it doesn't.

Comment: @ArtursLicis - why? that's changed by user -that's the whole point I thought!

Comment: @Fakrudeen ahh, I confused with another situation. That's right, just check if a class file is older than source file => need recompile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the Maven compiler plugin uses last modified dates on the source and class files to determine whether recompilation is necessary.

The compiler [website](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) is rather short on information, but the `compiler:compile` goal page has information on the following attribute, which finely tunes the staleness calculations: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#staleMillis. That's about the only official statement regarding staleness.

Comment: Guess my belief is wrong and it does use last modified property. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @duncan-jones where modified date is saved. I didn't find information in "target" folder. for example I changed two classes in one hour run compile, than in one hour change one of two classes. how manen find out what is the files is changed

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing much about maven, I can tell you that generally speaking, "make"-like tools use the "last changed" timestamp, which would explain the issue you had with svn ( see [Wikipedia on Subversion's weaknesses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion#Limitations_and_problems).

Answer (score 0):

Robert Scholte's comment at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-205 explains the process. It depends on the "useIncrementalCompilation" option of the "maven-compiler-plugin" (and on the version of it btw, I've only managed to have "useIncrementalCompilation" work with 3.1, not 3.0):

> I see there's some confusion, so something needs to be changed, maybe
>   improving documentation is good enough. Looking at the code, you'll
>   see that non-incremental will only look at changed sourcefiles.
>   Incremental will also verifies if dependencies have changed and if
>   files have been added or removed. If it has changed, it'll remove the
>   complete classes-directory. The reason is that the default java
>   compiler is quite fast, likely much faster than analyzing per file
>   what to do with it. IIUC the eclipse compiler is a real incremental
>   compiler, so we could decide that based that based on the used
>   compiler not to drop the classes directory.

Comment: just noticed at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html, that the "useIncrementalCompilation" says "since 3.1"